# database Junction/association table with more data fields

Tags: sql, database-design, many-to-many

I am not a fan of having more than two fields (eg: pk1 & pk2) in a junction/association table. I do have a situation, however, and not sure what would be the best approach to resolve it.

Table 1: 
Contract (id, price, description)

Table 2:
Person (id, firstname, lastname)

Table 3 (junction/association)
person_contract (person_id, contract_id)

So a contract can have one ore more persons and a person can have one or more contracts. Hence the need for a junction/association table; person_contract.

Up to here there is no problem. Now persons per contract have a sequence to represents their importance to a given contract. For example: 
- person1, contract1, sequence = 1
- person2, contract1, sequence = 2
- person3, contract1, sequence = 3
- person1, contract2, sequence = 2
- person4, contract2, sequence = 1

The question is where to save the person sequence for a contract? Adding the sequence to the junction/association table doesn't look right to me. I am looking for a better approach if possible.

Comment: Do you have any reason for not wanting to put it in the junction table other than not liking how it looks? I certainly have tables models exactly in that way, with a third column labelled something like Rank to allow queries to pull many-to-many associations back in a certain order. I also have junction tables with other fields added. If that table leads to the correct cardinality and suits all of your needs, why not add the field there? What makes a junction table different to any other table in your mind?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity Particularly note: "... it is also an entity since it may have its own properties." and "... may also contain ... other information about the relationship."

Comment: Thanks @jo-douglass. I ended up adding the field to the junction table as there is no other options.

Comment: OK - I'll write up a proper answer in that case, might help someone else who's wondering about this in future.

Comment: The reason I didn't want to add it is because I use JBoss hibernate tools to generate entities from the DB tables. When the junction table had only 2 primary key fields, the generated code was very neat and clean. Once I added the sequence field to the table and regenerated code, the result was a bit of a mess. I thought maybe it's not the right way to do it. At the end, I generated the code without the field in there, then added it afterwards. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: It might be worth editing your question to explain that Hibernate and the code it auto generated was the reason you were questioning the table design - including the fact that you had to generate the code without any other fields, then add them after. Other people might well run into the same issue with Hibernate, and they'll be more likely to find this question if it includes those points. You could even tag Hibernate if you think that's suitable. (Comments can easily be deleted on SE and it's best to consider them temporary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with including other fields in  this kind of table. For the specific scenario you've described, it can actually be quite useful as you could add a Rank column, and then use that to sort the people associated with a contract if you want to find the most important person. I have used a very similar pattern before with success.

Thinking about this from a data modelling perspective, in entity-relationship terminology this is an associative entity. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) has this to say about the matter:

- "[An associative entity] is also an entity since it may have its own properties."
- "[An associative entity] may also contain ... other information about the relationship."

So if some data is about the relationship modelled by a particular table, then it belongs in that table.

I often find it helpful to step out of database thinking with this kind of thing - rather than seeing it as a junction table, you could think about it as a group of people who sign a contract together. The importance data you were questioning conceptually describes something about that group of people in regards to a specific contract.

As far as your note in the comment that you started thinking this might be problematic because of how Hibernate generated entities based on the tables, I have seen some very questionable things created by ORM tools in both directions (i.e. poorly auto-generated databases and poorly auto-generated code). Questioning the output - as you have done - seems sensible. I don't know whether these issues are something that can be worked around or whether it's the inescapable cost of using auto-generation tools; it could be worth a new question aimed at Hibernate experts as to whether you can get it to accept this kind of table and still auto-generate decent code.